# Is there a way to add positionObserver sorts similar to IntersectionObserver or MutationObserver offered in Web APIs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, webapi

I am trying to implement a "position change" watcher to notice any changes in the component I am writing w.r.t its position based on Window.

Is there any way to watch and observe if the element's position changed (due to scroll or swipe etc) and trigger an event?

Please note this is a component. Meaning, it can sit in any level of DOM or under any container. Most of the solutions I tried (IntersectionObserver, finding the nearest scrollable container, polling etc) are too costly performance or achieve 30% of the solution at the maximum.

I can elaborate on any part of the question if it sounds too vague or ambiguous.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, I can't quite grasp why a Mutation Observer wouldn't do the job for you, could you expand a bit on the problem? Thanks.

Comment: As far as I understand, mutationObserver triggers a change of any sorts, but not w.r.t position. Please advise if that's not the case.
Please note, I need to fire the moment a position change occurs. That's why I am stuck :(

Comment: So is it only on a scroll (or equivalent)? I don't quite understand, because if it's scroll won't its position have moved so you'll need to check every scroll event?

Comment: Yes. But, the situation complicates when there are nested scrolls and identifying a position change even in such scenarios becomes too particular as an implementation.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you could put up a small piece of working code that shows what you are trying to achieve, I've not grasped why combinations of mutation observer and watching scrolling won't work.

Comment: @AHaworth you are correct when it comes to the combination part. But even if there are 5 elements under observation this way, it's adding a lot of processing burden on the system, slowing down other actions too. 

I was (sort of) able to work around it by placing a div that is exactly the same dimension as the element to be observed. Add mutation observer with respect to this new div (which is position absolute) and completed the implementation. It kind of was fast and had a reduced impact on performance.